# How to scaffold a dbcontext with the new EF 6.4?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6.4

i updated the Entity Framework in a Windows Desktop application to 6.4 and read about the new features. Seeing that EF 6.4 is now based on EF Core 3.0 i would like to get rid of the .edmx files and use the command-line scaffolding options that EF Core offers.

How does one migrate from clunky .edmx files to the command line generation? Is this even possible with the new EF (without switching to EF Core)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, EF 6.4 isn't based on EF Core 3.0. It's the next version of EF 6, ported to .NET Core. You don't need EF Core 3 to get rid of EDMX though. Code-First was introduced with EF 4.1, 8 years ago. You can already use scaffolding tools with EF 6

Comment: Check [Code first to an existing database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the link. This is very helpful and for sure simpler than handling the .edmx file for every DB change. But is there a way to do it on the command-line only, EF Core "style"? Thanks again

Comment: I've also come across this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/ telling Create model from database: Command line - yes - EF6.4.
We also use EF6.4 and making changes to database and re-create edmx, context.cs and other generated classes with VS GUI. I am very excited if the same can be done with command line tooling. I could not find this option in ef.exe.